# Background color of MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_TEXT_TOP in NSIS

Tags: background-color, nsis

How to change the Background color of MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_TEXT_TOP in NSIS?

The function SetCtlColor is not working.

I even tried to find the ItemID,but could not find the correct ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
!include MUI.nsh
Var MySMDir
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_TEXT_TOP "Blah blah"
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW OnStartmenuPageShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_STARTMENU SMD $MySMDir
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Function OnStartmenuPageShow
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT ; Find the inner dialog
GetDlgItem $0 $0 0x3EB

/* Uncomment to use MUI specific ways of finding the control
!if "${MUI_SYSVERSION}" >= 2.0
GetDlgItem $0 $mui.StartMenuPage 0x3EB
!else
GetDlgItem $0 $MUI_HWND 0x3EB
!endif */

SetCtlColors $0 774411 aaccff
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: I am using version 1.8 and aborting Welcome page as per my project requirement.
$MUI_HWND is undefined.

I tried enabling the Welcome Page too, but it did not work.

Side Question: How do you find the id "0x3EB" ? and is there any other way to get $MUI_HWND's value when I abort the Welcome Page ?

Comment: $MUI_HWND is documented as valid in the startmenu show function! Posting your code that does not work would help but I'll edit my answer to use a general method...

Comment: I'm using Ultra Modern UI.. UMUI.nsh.. and it is not applying the color for ID 0x3EB by using the above method. I read a little about StartMenu dll and it has the ID 1003 for changing the colors on a custom page.

Unfortunately, I'm still unable make the changes in SHOW function of MUI_PAGE_STARTMENU.

Comment: I don't understand why you wait this long to tell us that you are using a 3rd-party UI toolkit! My code works in MUI v1 and v2, I don't know anything about UMUI...

Comment: I see that UMUI has something called AlternativeStartMenu. If you want to find the Id of the controls there you can use a spy tool like WinSpy++...